# add mask to numbers using ClosedXML C#

Tags: c#, excel, number-formatting, closedxml

I fulfill Excel with `DataTable` using `ClosedXML` and one of the column has numbers with 11 or 14 digits.
Depending on number of digits I would like to put mask on a number like:

11 digits : `"000.000.000-00"`

14 digits : `"00.000.000/0000-00"`

I tried the code below

```
for (int j = 2; j <= lastrow; j++)
{
    ws.Cell(j, 4).Style.NumberFormat.Format = ws.Cell(j, 4).Value.ToString().Count() <= 11 ? "000.000.000-00" : "00.000.000/0000-00";
}
```

But didnt work. Thank You for help.

Comment: Put a single quote before the first digit so it gets treated like a string.  Use NumberFormat.Format = "@".  The format would be exactly the same if you did it manually in excel.  I normally do thing manually before writing code.

Comment: Excuse me, bu t I do not understand. You mean something like "@'000.000.000-00" ?

Comment: The "@" indicates format is TEXT.